# Understand an online contract with no EVM bytecode avaliable

Tags: evm, etherscan, bytecode

Could anyone shed some lights on the following contract?

https://etherscan.io/address/0x27d6c4cb2551799a143e1a3291ae002b8c8aa078#code

I am quite confused about what's going on here. Why doesn't the "EVM bytecode" of the contract show up on `etherscan.io`? Or it is because it has been self destructed or something?

Any suggestion would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code is indeed missing as etherscan cannot link it easily.

If you switch to OPCODE View, you're going to find the following:

```
PUSH20 0x273930d21e01ee25e4c219b63259d214872220a2
PUSH2 0x235a
GAS
SUB
CALLCODE
```

Judging by the time the contract was deployed and the code it's using ( CALLCODE ) we can determine that it's actually delegating it's storage and execution to another contract.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x273930d21e01ee25e4c219b63259d214872220a2#code

Now you have the actual ABI and source code that you can use to create calls against it.

These days instead of CALLCODE, we use DELEGATECALL for such cases.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Micky! That makes a lot of sense to me. Just one quick question, so instead of "fixing" the delegated code address, is it possible to make it dynamic?

Comment: So what I means is that, given this contract, since it dispatches its functionality to another contract, I would like to link with that contract and do some analysis. If the address of "that contract" is hard coded, then I guess it's feasible to link. Otherwise if it is dynamically determined, then I guess I will have no way to do that.

Comment: 1 - For analysis and usage think about this contract, as a "proxy" that just delegates calls to the master contract. In essence you don't really need to know what the "master's address is" because the child knows and transfers calls internally. In this case it's hard coded due to the way it was created ( most likely a Library ).

Comment: 2 - There are more advanced implementations, that implement call delegation manually that CAN have a dynamic "master", being that they store that in a variable, in which case you can determine when it changes. You should probably read up on DELEGATECALL and upgradeable smart contracts as well as https://blog.zeppelinos.org/proxy-patterns/

Comment: Very interesting analysis! And how did they succeed in having the ABI instead of the source code on etherscan?

Comment: @rick-park if you take a closer look at the etherscan page it does say "Contract ABI  (Uses ABI Data From Contract 0x86018025a553d3e88b38dc5409e4b52edeb9ab83)", that suggests it either detected it somehow, or someone manually added the ABI on that contract at one point :). Since the "Write Contract" was added just a few months back, and it does not work here it stands to reason the contract's ABI interface was added quite a while back.

Comment: Thanks Micky. I do not know how to obtain this. I’ll try to understand more